# How to hide shadow root in the element inspector panel?

Tags: shadow-dom, google-developer-tools

I use some web component libs like "LitElement" and I don't want to inspect all of the shadow doms. I only foucs on codes I write. Is there any way to hide them?

Comment: Well, I wrote a wrong title. I want to hide shadow dom.

Comment: No you can't do that

Comment: so sad. Looks like I have to post an issue on dev-tools repository